# deploying cloud functions on firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I need to deploy a cloud function on firebase  to set  admin role:
this is my code:

```
  typescript
  "use strict";
  import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
  import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
  admin.initializeApp();
  exports.adAddminRole = functions.https.onCall((data) => {
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then((user) => {
  return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {
    admin: true,
  }).then(() => {
    return {
      message: ` Success! ${data.email} as been made an admin`,
    };
  }).catch((err) => {
    return err;
  });
});
});
```

when I do  firebase deploy --only functions, I get  a lot of error messages:

```
../node_modules/@types/google.maps/index.d.ts:19:1 - error 
TS6200: Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with 
those in another file: DEFAULT, HORIZONTAL_BAR, DROPDOWN_MENU, 
BOTTOM_CENTER, BOTTOM_LEFT, BOTTOM_RIGHT, LEFT_BOTTOM, 
LEFT_CENTER, LEFT_TOP, RIGHT_BOTTOM, RIGHT_CENTER, RIGHT_TOP, 
TOP_CENTER, TOP_LEFT, TOP_RIGHT

19 declare namespace google.maps {
~~~~~~~

../node_modules/@types/googlemaps/reference/control.d.ts:1:1
1 declare namespace google.maps {
  ~~~~~~~
Conflicts are in this file.

it looks to me that they are not related  directly to the cloud 
function's code, I do not understand what is wrong
```

Comment: You're MUCH more likely to get an answer if you actually paste at least SOME of the errors here - you really shouldn't make us have to do extra work to chase down your link.

Comment: These look like build errors, not deploy errors.

Comment: how can I fix it?

Comment: [Here](https://localcoder.org/error-ts6200-definitions-of-the-following-identifiers-conflict-with-those-in-an) are some solutions to fix build errors. which might help you